# Constraining norms with inequalities

Tags: r, optimization

I have time-series data for N stocks.

`sample.data<-rep(10,rnorm(100))`, where each column shows the returns of different stocks over time.

I am trying to construct a portfolio weight vector to minimize the variance of the returns.

the objective function:

```
min w^{T}\sum w
s.t. e_{n}^{T}w=1
\left \| w \right \|\leq C
```

where w is the vector of weights, `\sum` is the covariance matrix, `e_{n}^{T}` is a vector of ones, `C` is a constant. Where the second constraint (`\left \| w \right \|`) is an inequality constraint.

Is there any function in R that can do this?
I tried using `solve.QP()` from the `quadprog` package, but it is not clear how to impose the inequality constraint for the norm of the weight vector.

The following code solves the problem if the second constraint was simply `w \leq C`
instead  `\left \| w \right \|\leq C`

```
cov.Rt<-cov(sample.data)
A.eq<-matrix(1,nrow(cov.Rt),ncol=1)
B.eq<-1
A.neq<-diag(10)
B.neq<-matrix(0,nrow=10,ncol=1)

A<-cbind(A.eq,A.neq)
B<-c(B.eq,B.neq)
mu<-colMeans(sample.data)

solve.QP(cov.Rt,mu,A,B,meq=1)
```

How can this code be modified to solve the above problem for norms?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a statistics question, it is an R programming question. Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See packages **Rsolnp** and **alabama**. Also I suspect you can restate your problem so that it is a [convex optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization) problem. When searching for an R package it is always good idea to check [CRAN Task views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/). [Optimization view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) lists all the available packages which provide optimization algorithms.